# Inherit from a model and change table for all purposes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Class that defines an opened ticket and another one for closed tickets:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  [validations]
  [callbacks]
end

class ClosedTicket < Ticket
  self.table_name = "closed_tickets"
end
```

And I want to move the tickets that are closed to the `closed_tickets` table. But when the model performs the validations, it does using the superclass table name, and consequently they fail.

```
ClosedTicket.table_name => "closed_tickets"
ClosedTicket.create(Ticket.first.attributes)
Ticket Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `tickets` WHERE...
=> ["ID has already been taken"]

ClosedTicket.table_name => "closed_tickets"
closed_ticket = ClosedTicket.new(Ticket.first.attributes)
closed_ticket.save
Ticket Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `tickets` WHERE...
```

I don't have a single clue on how to fix the table name for all methods and validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did two models and abstracted all common methods into a module and composed into the two models. I wasn't able to find any better solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClosedTicket.table_name => "closed_tickets"
closed_ticket = ClosedTicket.new(Ticket.first.attributes)
closed_ticket.save
```

Comment: Updated the question, I already tryed this and the problem is the same.